# understand why the following equality hold

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{f_j\}$ be a sequence of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$-valued measurable functions on a measurable space $(X,\scr{M})$ define $g(x)=\sup_j f_j(x)$. We have $$g^{-1}((a,\infty])=\bigcup^\infty f_j^{-1}((a,\infty])$$.

I dont even see this intuitively.

Here is what I did trying to understand this,
Suppose $x\in g^{-1}((a,\infty])$ then since $g$ is defined to be the sup, there must exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f_k(x)=g(x)>a$ and hence $x\in \bigcup^\infty f_j^{-1}((a,\infty])$. Conversely, let $x\in \bigcup^\infty f_j^{-1}((a,\infty])$, there exists $k$ such that $f_k(x)>a$ then I just dont see an argument I can pull here. I must be missing something. Can someone point out??

Also, even if I was able to prove this equality, I just don't see the equality intuitively.
Thanks!

Comment: It  is immediate from the definition of the supremum of a set of real numbers.

Comment: Since $g(x)=\sup_j f_j(x)$, we have that: $x \in g^{-1}((a,\infty])$ if and only if  $g(x) > a$ if and only if there is $j$ such that $f_j(x) > a$  if and only if there is $j$ such that $x \in f_j^{-1}((a,\infty])$ if and only if  $ x \in \bigcup^\infty f_j^{-1}((a,\infty])$. So, $$g^{-1}((a,\infty])=\bigcup^\infty f_j^{-1}((a,\infty])$$.